# A Quick Chess Puzzle in Passing

Tags: lateral-thinking, chess

[image]

White to move and mate in 3.

Hint:

> The title may contain a clue.

Comment: This is mate in 3, not mate in 2. The title gives away the solution, but this is against the accepted convention for chess problems that you can do such a thing only if you can **prove** that the opponent has just done what he has just done.

Answer (score 5):

I suppose the title refers to

> taking *en passant*

but I can only get a mate in 3...

> 1.  dxc6+ Bc4
>  2. Bxc4+ d5
>  3. Bxd5#

Comment: Yeah, this is what I was thinking too! Good spot with the mate in 3, I think this is correct. +1

Comment: Beaten by a minute, again!?

Comment: Didn’t you get me this time?? @jafe

Comment: If you’re on the website and you hover over the minutes it should give you a UTC timestamp for each post...I’m on mobile right now but think you nipped me by 20 seconds @jafe

Comment: @El-Guest ah, I see now... yesss!

Answer (score 2):

I think the first move could be

> 1. dxc5+ e.p. , based on the title...but then 
>  1. ... Bc4 isn’t mate because of 
>  2. Bxc4+ d5...

I suppose the mate in 2 includes suboptimal play, namely

> 1. dxc5+ e.p. d5 
>  2. Bxd5#